# How to elaborate my program by using an account name appended with an integer to distinguish different account names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my question, For the account name above, if an account name already exists, use an account name appended with an integer to distinguish different account names. For example, if there are three patients with the same account name “abranch”, the second one should be named as “abranch1” and the third one should be named as “abranch2”. How to elaborate my program by using an account name appended with an integer to distinguish different account names?

Here's is my code for generating the name list:

```
 with open('all_patients.txt', 'r') as fh:


    for line in fh:

        splited_list = line.split()
        surname = splited_list[1]
        given_name = splited_list[0][0]
        patient_name_u = given_name + surname
        patient_name.append(patient_name_u.lower())

fh.close()
print(patient_name)
```

Comment: why you are closing file when you are already using `with` ?

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like this

```
abranch
abranch
abranch
```

Then you can use `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
with open("file.txt") as f:
    d = [f"{names}_{time}" for names, times in Counter(f.read().splitlines()).items() for time in range(times) ]
print(d)
#['abranch_0', 'abranch_1', 'abranch_2']
```